# Are the SpaceX related blogs (software-in-space), blogs or advertorials?

Tags: discussion, support, advertising, blog

Recently several blogs tagged [software-in-space](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/software-in-space/) have appeared. They very much read like one big advertisement, with some information sprinkled through. This reminded me more of advertorials then blogs. Especially with the marketing lines at the end of every blog in this series:

> If you want to learn more about working in software at SpaceX, check out [their careers page](https://www.spacex.com/careers/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=blog-1). For the other blog posts in this series, you can [check out the rest of our series](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/software-in-space/).

#### Is this blog series a paid partnership?

If so, what would be the best way to disclaim that in these blogs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Director of content marketing at Stack Overflow here.

This series was not a paid promotion. We partnered with SpaceX to do a series about software that we thought the Stack Overflow community would find interesting. The response has been tremendous, and we hope to do more series like this with other companies who rely on software to power innovative new approaches to their industry.

Comment: Hey Benjamin, thanks for your answer, and welcome to MSE.

Comment: Was any exchange of money, goods, or services involved in this partnership, or was it entirely altruistic?

Comment: hey @forestdistrustsStackExchange - there was no exchange of value beyond exposure to a lot of developers for them and pieces that drove good readership for us